# Spring mvc 405 - 403 ошибки

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Что делать? Использую Spring mvc+Spring Security (non-boot) - если csrf отключить, то не отдает html ресурсы под ошибкой 405, если включить - под ошибкой 403. Я не собираюсь реализовывать этот протокол, как мне его обойти? Моя конфигурация:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider provider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable() // <------------ Вот она
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/hello", "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(provider));
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Если конкретнее, не проходит логин юзера метод POST (об ошибке 405 - мол, его типа нету) - но вот он, на месте:

```
//    @PostMapping("/login")
//    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> login(@RequestBody AuthRequestDto dto) {
//        try {
//            String username = dto.getUsername();
//            String password= dto.getPassword();
//            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
//            User user = userService.findUserByUsername(username);
//
//            if (user == null) {
//                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username: " + username + " not found");
//            }
//
//            String token = provider.createToken(username, user.getRoles());
//
//            Map<String, String> response = Map.of(
//                    "username", username,
//                    "token", token
//            );
//
//            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
//        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
//            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password!");
//        }
//    }
```

Comment: Ну вроде логично, что если `csrf` включен, а токены не передаются, то 403 access denied. А если отключено, то проверки токенов нет, но 405 говорит о том, что запрос `/login` не поддерживает такого метода. Остается вопрос почему вы скинули закомментированный метод, может в этом дело? Но еще возможно, что адрес `/login` совпадает с `loginPage` конфигуратора формы авторизации. Попробуйте изменить ваш `url` на какой-нибудь другой.

Comment: я ак сильно похожа на дурочку)) нет, закоментирован он не поэтому, я искала причину, а раскомментировать поленилась

Comment: чекните версию с урлом, т.к. `/login` может быть зарезервирован в `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer`

Comment: да( пыталась уже. Кажется просто рест со страничкаи работать не сильно хочет

Comment: Я бы режим дебага или трассировки тогда включил, чтобы понимать почему 405  но явно он находит `@GetMapping`, раз ругается что на этом url нет `@PostMapping`

Comment: Может быть, стоит использовать Spring Security для аутентификации? Вы подключили Spring Security, и теперь пропускаете всю его реализацию аутентификации. Зачем? Реализуйте UserDetaisService.